# Is it enough to use set_time_limit in php when requesting webservices?

Tags: php

Let's say I need to call a webservice several times in the same php function, to avoid my page hanging out if webservice fails for some reason, is it enough to set_time_limit in php ? What's the best practices ?

Also I just read set_time_limit doesn't work when in safe_mode then what should I use ?

Comment: I belive that it is not that you can't set it, but more like you can't CHANGE it, you script will by default expire within the default time_limit value in place.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you're calling the web service, you may specify a timeout.

- With the http wrapper, there's the [`timeout`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) wrapper context option for connection timeout.
- If the connection is already established and you're manipulating, PHP streams, you can use [`stream_set_timeout()`](http://www.php.net/stream_set_timeout) to specify a timeout.
- With curl, there are the [options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` and their millisecond variants.
- <del>For [SoapClient](http://php.net/SoapClient), you can pass on [construction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) a stream context, though I don't know its options (I imagine they may be the same as the http wrapper – I'll check this in a moment and then I'll update the answer).</del> By code inspection, this stream context is passed to a transport stream (`tcp` or `ssl`) and therefore cannot be used to set a timeout. The timeout of a SoapClient can be set by [changing the property `_connection_timeout`](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/ext/soap/php_http.c?revision=299903&view=markup#l108).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you call the service. Sockets and streams have parameters for setting timeout on connecting or general timeout for the socket, which helps a lot.

You can give it a look on http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php and also check the manual for sockets if you use sockets.